# Grouping by year in R

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr

I have a dataset where I want to group by year (and sum over `days`), but if the number of `days` for a certain `date` is more than the number of days that have occurred in the year so far, the extra days should be added to the previous year. For example, below, out of the 153 days associated with `2019-02-01`, 31 of the days should go towards 2019 and 122 should go towards 2018.

**Data**

```
dat <- data.frame(date = as.Date( c("2018-02-01", "2018-06-01", "2018-07-01", "2018-09-01", "2019-02-01", "2019-03-01", "2019-04-01") ),
                  days = c(0, 120, 30, 62, 153, 28, 31))

date         days
2018-02-01   0
2018-06-01   120
2018-07-01   30
2018-09-01   62
2019-02-01   153
2019-03-01   28
2019-04-01   31
```

**Expected output**

```
year   days
2018   334
2019   90
```

How can I do this in R? (ideally using `dplyr`, but base-R is fine if that's the only way)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one way using base R :

```
#Get day of the year
dat$day_in_year <- as.integer(format(dat$date, "%j"))
#Get year from date
dat$year <- as.integer(format(dat$date, "%Y"))
#Index where day in year is less than days
inds <- dat$day_in_year < dat$days
#Create a new dataframe with adjusted values
other_df <- data.frame(days = dat$days[inds] - dat$day_in_year[inds] + 1, 
                       year = dat$year[inds] - 1)
#Update the original data
dat$days[inds] <- dat$day_in_year[inds] - 1

#Combine the two dataframe then aggregate
aggregate(days~year, rbind(dat[c('days', 'year')], other_df), sum)

#  year days
#1 2018  334
#2 2019   90
```

Comment: Great answer. I was also able to turn this into a `dplyr` version for my project.

Answer (score 3):

A possible `tidyverse` way:

```
library(tidyverse)

dat %>% group_by(year = as.integer(format(date, '%Y'))) %>%
  mutate(excess = days - (date - as.Date(paste0(year, '-01-01'))),
    days = ifelse(excess > 0, days - excess, days)) %>%
  summarise(days = sum(days), excess = as.integer(sum(excess[excess > 0]))) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  complete(year = seq(min(year), max(year)), fill = list(excess = 0)) %>%
  mutate(days = days + lead(excess, default = 0), excess = NULL)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  year   days
  <chr> <dbl>
1 2018    334
2 2019     90
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @arg0naut91. Here, could you explain what `case_when(excess > 0 ~ 0L, TRUE ~ excess[year %in% year + 1])` is doing?

Comment: It took the next value (year) if it had residual days, but then the assumptions behind were not robust - I've changed the code to something that should work in many scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

Basically using `tapply`, getting the year from the first four character `substr`ing.

```
data.frame(days=with(dat, tapply(days, substr(date, 1, 4), sum)))
#      days
# 2018  212
# 2019  212
```

If the year is needed as column, probably better using `aggregate`.

```
with(dat, aggregate(list(days=days), list(date=substr(date, 1, 4)), sum))
#   date days
# 1 2018  212
# 2 2019  212
```

To get the **transfer** one year back, we could write a function `fun` that subtracts, to get the transfers `tr`.

```
fun <- function(d) d - as.Date(paste0(substr(d, 1, 4), "-01-01"))
tr <- with(dat, as.numeric(days - fun(date)))
```

`tapply` solution:

```
res <- data.frame(days=with(dat, tapply(days, substr(date, 1, 4), sum)))
transform(res, days=days + tr[tr > 0] * c(1, -1))

#      days
# 2018  334
# 2019   90
```

Similar using `aggregate`:

```
res2 <- with(dat, aggregate(list(days=days), 
                            list(date=substr(date, 1, 4)), sum))
transform(res2, days=days + tr[tr > 0] * c(1, -1))
#   date days
# 1 2018  334
# 2 2019   90
```

---

*Data:*

```
dat <- structure(list(date = structure(c(17563, 17683, 17713, 17775, 
17928, 17956, 17987), class = "Date"), days = c(0, 120, 30, 62, 
153, 28, 31)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```